# If double slash (//) is used 2 times in XPath, what does it mean?

Tags: xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

What does a double-slash used twice in an XPath selector mean?

Suppose I'm using a path like:

```
//div[@id='add']//span[@id=addone']
```

Answer (score 76):

A double slash "`//`" means any descendant node of the current node in the HTML tree which matches the locator.

A single slash "`/`" means a node which is a direct child of the current.

`//div[@id='add']//span[@id=addone']` will match:

```
<div id="add">
  <div>
    <span id="addone">
  </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
<div id="add">
    <span id="addone">
</div>
```

`//div[@id='add']/span[@id=addone']` will match only the second HTML tree.

Comment: "// is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/. For example, //para is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/child::para and so will select any para element in the document (even a para element that is a document element will be selected by //para since the document element node is a child of the root node); div//para is short for div/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para and so will select all para descendants of div children."

https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/

Comment: Since this is the top answer, I recommend changing "means any descendant node of the current node". Because "//" includes self. How about "means any descendant's nodes or self's node".

Comment: This little fact might be helpful too: In XPath when we say "-or-" it is the Set Theory "OR". It means "the union of". As opposed the Set Theory "AND" which means "intersection of". This is why "descendant-or-self" returns both self and descendants. [self] || [descendants]

Answer (score 40):

### Short answer

Each time a double slash (`//`) is used in XPath, selection will proceed by testing not only the context node (`self::`) but also all of the descendants of the context node. <sup>1</sup>

Detailed explanation follows...

### Basics

- Use `//*` to select ***all elements***  in the document.
- Use `.//*` to select ***all descendants of the current element***.
- Use `/*` to select the ***root element*** of the document.
- Use `./*` to select ***all immediate children of the current element***.

### Technical details

Double slash (`//`) is the descendant-or-self axis; it is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`.

In your example XPath:

```
//div[@id='add']//span[@id='addone']
```

- The first time `//` appears, it selects all `div` elements in the
  document with an `id` attribute value equal to `'add'`.
- The second time `//` appears, it selects all `span` elements that are
  descendents of each of the `div` elements selected previously.
- Note that using two double slashes twice is different than just using
  double slash once.  For example, `//span[@id='addone']` would select
  ***all*** `span` elements with `@id='addone'` in the entire document, regardless of whether they are a descendent of a `div` with `@id='add'`.

---

<sub>1. Note that currently the top-voted answer means to say that the `span` elements in the shown examples would be *selected*, *not* the shown `div` element contexts — that answer uses an misleading notion of "matching" where the standard uses "selecting" more precisely to prescribe required behavior.  To understand XPath, think in terms of *selection*, not *matching*.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

If you'd have this:

```
<div id='add'>
   <ul>
      <li>
        <span id='add one' />
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Then

```
//div[@id='add']//span[@id='addone']
```

will result in the `span` because the second `//` means you look for any child relative to

```
div[@id='add']
```

that is `span[@id='add one']`.

If you'd use one slash

```
//div[@id='add']/span[@id='addone']
```

then of course you won't find it because then you look for a direct child and you'd have to use

```
//div[@id='add']/ul/li/span[@id='addone']
```

So the second `//` is very useful in avoiding extra hierarchy in your XPaths.