# Unable to click the Select image button nested inside span

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm unable to click the "Select Image" button. Here is the html:

```
<tr ng-controller="MasterImageController" ng-init="init(0)" class="ng-scope">
    <td rowspan="2" valign="top"></td>
    <td>
        <div class="alert alert-success" style="display: none;" id="masterImageMessageContainer">
            <span id="masterImageMessage">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="btn btn-success btn-file">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture">
                    ::before
                </span>
                " Select image "
                <input type="file" name="masterImage-file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().masterImageFileChanged(this)" value="" id="masterImage-file">
            </span>
            <span class="ng-binding"></span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tried:

```
By.xpath("input[@name='masterImage-file']"))
```

but unable to click the button just by this xpath. There is no frame.

Error shows:

> Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: input[@name='masterImage-file'] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

another message shows

> Unable to find the element.

I did add `Thread.sleep(1500);`

Comment: Updated the code to By.xpath("//input[@name='masterImage-file']")  Now I don't get any error, still Button is not clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could prefix this with a [double slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019544/if-double-slash-is-used-2-times-in-xpath-what-does-it-mean) `//`

`//input[@name='masterImage-file']`

You might also use the id to make sure it is unique `//input[@id='masterImage-file']`

Comment: I tried that // too, but did not work. Now I don't see any error after adding //

Answer (score 0):

The *Select Image* is not within the `<input>` tag but within the `<span>` tag. To click on the *Select Image* button you can use the following *Locator Strategy* :

```
By.xpath("//tr[@class='ng-scope']//td//span[btn btn-success btn-file]")
```

The element being a *Angular Element* you may need to induce *WebDriverWait* before clicking as follows (**Java**) :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//tr[@class='ng-scope']//td//span[btn btn-success btn-file]"))).click();
```

Update :

You can get a bit more granular and use the following line of code :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//tr[@class='ng-scope']//td//span[btn btn-success btn-file]/span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-picture']"))).click();
```

Comment: Code looks quite promising @DebanjanB, but not sure what's wrong here it is not focusing on the Select Image button.

Comment: Added an update to my answer. Let me know the status.

Comment: Nope, did not help so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you aren't using just the ID.

```
By locator = By.id("masterImage-file");
```

If this ID isn't unique on the page, this is another option

```
By locator = By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Select image')]//input");
```

I would also add a wait to make sure the element is loaded. It could be that part of the page is slow loading

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();
```

If that doesn't work for some reason, you need to investigate:

1. Is this element in an IFRAME? I know you said it isn't but you should check again. This is a typical cause of these kinds of errors.
2. Is this element unique on the page? Open the dev console in Chrome with the page open and try `$$("#masterImage-file")`. Does it return more than 1 element? If it does, that's probably the problem. You'll have to find another way to reference just this `INPUT`.

Comment: It is a unique element on the page and not inside a frame I checked it twice and the code you wrote also does not recognize the element.

Comment: Then there's something crucial you are missing in your question. There's no reason some of this shouldn't work. Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: It is on the CMS page which would need a login /password, so can't be provided and I don't see anything I've missed to provide.