# RegEX (preg_match_all) to retrieve Authenticity Token from Hidden Login Form

Tags: php, regex, curl, preg-match-all

Short in short I'm trying to use CURL to log-in to the eCommerce Platform Bonanza so that I can auto-print new orders that come in.

I searched on GitHub and found an auto-login script for twitter [here](https://github.com/alperensert/twitter-curl-login/blob/master/config.php) which looks extremely similar to how Bonanza operates.

The login page I'm trying to execute my curl request first off is located [here](https://www.bonanza.com/home/login)

It includes a form that POSTS the following variables to log you in

```
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: 0tMPrfH0+Tt7z05jxu61pN10RveVp6o0dsfgf=4cS6g7kyeMsztpDmWj2P1ZYasfdf3QjNl/og==
username: myusername
password: mypassword
commit: Log in
```

Viewing the source for the form you can see the `name="authenticity_token"` and `value=` of the token I need to retrieve.

```
 <form class="user_session_form"
 action="https://www.bonanza.com/sessions" accept-charset="UTF-8"
 method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;"
 /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="siKgYUtSqTs8DHCXmj8gbV6Gp3L7gaQ9C/B0rLM9/V94+FnSxTb+x6vXADSFROCxxMLB3RAqOMeL/IJQADq6dk8A=="
 />
```

As stated, this seems to be very similiar to how the Twitter log-in script works, as it finds the Authentication Token, and makes a POST request to *https://twitter.com/sessions* with the variables passed to successfully login.

The twitter script uses this preg_match_all function to obtain the authentication token

```
function ara($ilk, $son, $text) {
    @preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($ilk, '/') .
    '(.*?)'. preg_quote($son, '/').'/i', $text, $m);
    return @$m[1];
}
```

And here is how the function is used to get the authentication token...

```
$baslik = ara("<input type=\"hidden\" value=", "\" name=\"authenticity_token\">", $html);
```

note (`$html`) is the curl exec for the login page.

So to again to summarize, https://www.bonanza.com/home/login takes the following `formdata` to log-in:

> utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=SFrh%2FvFx7%2BH%2FA3kMQ2WEfZ23423AlbtP3bfT%2FaxQw7CwlgeUz5BBTMgtU7eHb%2BqyTnxs1TC30h64mT98mvA%3D%3D&username=myusername&password=mypassword&commit=Log+in

Makes a POST with these variables to https://www.bonanza.com/sessions to successfully log-in.

I'm trying to modify the twitter script the best I can, here's what I have thus far:

```
$username = "example@stackoverflow.com";
$password = "password"; 

$ch = curl_init();
$rand = rand(1,99999);
$cookie =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/cookie-$rand.txt";
$sTarget = "https://www.bonanza.com/home/login";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.bonanza.com/home/login");
$html = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote("<input type=\"hidden\" value=", '/') .
'(.*?)'. preg_quote("\" name=\"authenticity_token\">", '/').'/i', $html, $m);
```

// Not Working.. Need to retrieve `$authtoken` in `$m` `preg_match_all` array output

```
$sPost = "utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=$authtoken&username=$username&password=$password&commit=Log+in";
$sTarget = "https://www.bonanza.com/sessions";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
curl_exec($ch);
```

I've tried to debug and see if there is any output for `$m` in the `preg_match_all` call, but the output is an empty array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

How can I modify my preg_match_all call (or another method) to retrieve the `authenticity token` required for a successful form log-in submit, and is there anything else I should be aware of to log-in programatically via CURL in this way?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use `DOMDocument`, find the element by name, and get the value attribute.

Comment: That does make sense. I've never tried a log-in with CURL so I was just going with what I was finding.  So get the html contents with curl and load the HTML contents into a new `DOMDocument` to parse and find the authentication token?  Sounds easy enough actually. Still wondering if I'm missing something, there are so many options for CURL it can be overwhelming

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `curl`.

Comment: Well my current problem :) Unless you are stating the rest of the curl request looks like it should work to achieve my goal. I am just thinking ahead, I suppose. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I just meant the problem finding the authenticity token in the response. I didn't look at the curl code, I assumed you'd already confirmed that you're downloading the response correctly.

Comment: There were so many answers and comments I figured I'd go through them all and mention our unsung hero @Barmar. The first to answer with probably the most relevant solution with regards to, as he said, HTML parsing.

Comment: @bbruman - Note that regular expressions are and can be used to parse HTML _tags_. This is not parsing html at all. Dom's use regex to parse tags then create a tree structure of the related parts of a document. Since you just need info from a single tag, use regex. To use a Dom for this is a waste in terms of performance.

Comment: @Brian `preg_quote()` is most useful when it is fed variable input.  If you are passing a static string, just manually/statically escape any characters with special meaning.  In truth, your pattern doesn't need either `preg_quote()` call.  If you express your pattern using single quotes, you won't need the backslashes on your doublequotes.

Comment: Looking back that GitHub script was  kind of a weird way to get the token. And actually upon closer inspection it wasn't just in the form. I ended up using this: $tokens = $dom->getElementsByTagName("meta");
for ($i = 0; $i < $tokens->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $tokens->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'csrf-token')
    $token = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}. Regardless this post inspired me to get RegEx down.. is a very powerful tool and kind of fascinating. Like a language of it's own. Currently reading that O'Reilly book and working through them on projects, testing etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regex to get the authenticity token.
It comes out in capture group 4.

It doesn't matter the order of the attribute-values, this gets them
anywhere in the valid *input tag*.

`(?s)<input(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\stype\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*hidden\s*\1))(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sname\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*authenticity_token\s*\2))(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\svalue\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*(.*?)\s*\3))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>`

https://regex101.com/r/NCjFxc/1

***Quoting***

Single, Tilde as regex delimiter:
`'~(?s)<input(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"\']|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*?\stype\s*=\s*(?:([\'"])\s*hidden\s*\1))(?=(?:[^>"\']|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*?\sname\s*=\s*(?:([\'"])\s*authenticity_token\s*\2))(?=(?:[^>"\']|"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\')*?\svalue\s*=\s*(?:([\'"])\s*(.*?)\s*\3))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|\'[\S\s]*?\'|[^>]*?)+>~'`

Double, Tilde as regex delimiter:
`"~(?s)<input(?=\\s)(?=(?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*?\\stype\\s*=\\s*(?:(['\"])\\s*hidden\\s*\\1))(?=(?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*?\\sname\\s*=\\s*(?:(['\"])\\s*authenticity_token\\s*\\2))(?=(?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*?\\svalue\\s*=\\s*(?:(['\"])\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\3))\\s+(?:\"[\\S\\s]*?\"|'[\\S\\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>~"`

Readable version

```
 (?s)

 # Begin Input tag
 < input                # input tag

 (?= \s )
 (?=                    # Type Hidden (a pseudo atomic group)
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s type \s* = \s*      # Type
      (?:
           ( ['"] )               # (1), Quote
           \s* hidden \s*         # Hidden
           \1 
      )
 )
 (?=                    # Name authenticity_token
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s name \s* = \s*      # Name
      (?:
           ( ['"] )               # (2), Quote
           \s* authenticity_token \s*   # "Authenticity Token"
           \2 
      )
 )
 (?=                    # Value of authenticity_token
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s value \s* = \s*     # Value
      (?:
           ( ['"] )               # (3), Quote
           \s* 
           ( .*? )                # (4), Authenticity Token Value 
           \s* 
           \3 
      )
 )
 # Have the Authenticity Token, just match the rest of tag
 \s+ 
 (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+

 >                      # End tag
```

Comment: Thank you, now that is something. Honestly I'm struggling getting any of these answers to work -- probably due to my own misunderstandings of how to properly format these expressions.  Give me some more time to look into it and I'll figure them out for sure, it's just not happening right now for me. Invalid xpath errors, not knowing whether to use preg_match, preg_match_all, preg_quote or a combination of them.  Gonna have to dig deeper and figure out the solutions to these solutions. Example, no idea how to escape the multitude of single 's and double "s in your regex in my PHP script

Comment: @BrianBruman - Added the quoted versions. Yeah, if you want, just use preg_match for a single match, or preg_match_all. Either way..

Comment: Wow. That is crazy. May I suggest reducing the complexity by some 90%? `<input (?:(?:type=\"hidden\"|name=\"authenticity_token\"|value=\"([^"]+)\"|(?!(?:name|type|value))[^=]+=\"[^"]+\")\s*)+` captures 1 group which is the value desired.

Comment: Hey @BrianBruman -- I just saw your comment and corrected the xpath query in my code. I hadn't actually tested it previously. See the revision now. Anyway -- that approach is the approach you want. Play with the xpath query if you need to. There are plenty of sites you can paste HTML into a box and try to work out the query. A regex is the wrong solution for this unless you have very specific constraints indicating otherwise.

Comment: @Impact - Crazy, ok. Lets see, you're suggesting to me to reduce the complexity of what ? My regular expression ? I don't think you understand my regular expression a single bit. Come back when you do ...

Comment: @jstur - I see a lot of forcibly insistent people on SO demand that the asker not use regular expressions. If you want to peddle that trash, move your comment off of my answer ...

Comment: Thank you @sln you were the most helpful and yours was the only one that worked right out of the box. I made my comment in @jstur answer, there are many ways and what works for you works for you. It's probably a better skill to have than DOMDocument parsing, and it works. I appreciate the long-complex thread it will give me something to delve deep into as I'm trying to wrap my head around it more lately. @sln his regex brought back the solution that @Impact had `Warning: preg_match(): No ending matching delimiter '&gt;'`. Haven't had a chance to look into why yet. Assuming it's an easy fix..

Comment: You win by the way. Reasons stated and yours was the only one that worked as is. Other methods are, sure, up for debate, and I was just basing my question solely on information I found with the other twitter script.. and that question was very well answered and as stated worked perfectly to get what I wanted. Gave my other opinion in the other threads but I'll accept your answer tomorrow. Thank you again.

Comment: @sln your own link shows how many steps are needed to execute your pattern. The one I put in my first comment literally serves the same purpose: matching regardless of the attribute order. As for whether yours does anything extra for other scenarios, you're right, I don't know because I didn't bother to interpret it, because it is completely irrelevant. Why would anyone want a monstrous pattern to do a multitude of things, when they only need 1 aspect of it for 1 specific scenario? Elegance, efficiency, and maintainability are important things.

Comment: @Impact - I fear you don't understand regular expressions very well. All your verbosity gives you away in an instant. The _steps_ in a regex from regex101 are _not_ an indicator of performance, not even close. Your regex literally matches `<input donkey="bs"`, it has no validation of any required attr/vals, nor any semblance of other _valid_ parts of an html tag that may be present. You think out-of-order is as simple as using alternations .. you got a lot to learn. You wouldn't know regex if it smacked you in the face !

Comment: @sln uhm... my pattern doesn't fail when it encounters other attributes or values.  It matches then without capturing. It is simply, simpler. Your exaggerations only serve to make you sound arrogant. Regardless of who is the brightest bulb, the fact remains that there is but one purpose required of the pattern. Any variables aside from order (which has thus far been your only good point) is irrelevant, serving only to increase computation time, decrease readability, and add unnecessary and "unbeneficial" maintenance complexity...

Comment: @Impact - No exaggeration - you must come out of the dark ages my friend. Maintenance of regex has long been solved with tools like http://www.regexformat.com that do it all including benchmarking and Unicode. Tool's like this exponentially speed up the learning curve. A simple cure for you would be to learn more and faster. Since you give no indication of understanding of this regex, even with all the _hints_ I've given, it's probably useless to say more.

Comment: @sln Criticism is a healthy tool, not something to get offended and overly defensive at. It seens that yes, it is useless to say more. You're not succeeding in making a fool of me, and I'm getting no where talking to a brick wall. I feel I'd have to stoop to language like, "I bet you were that kid making web pages in dreamweaver drag and drop and thinking he was an accomplished web developer," in order to communicate with you, which is very sad and not what I created an account on this website to do. Thank you for your contribution; you're welcome for mine; good night.

Comment: @Impact  - Criticism is a healthy tool if your a qualified critic. If you're not, it's not an evaluation/suggestion, it's just noise.

Comment: @sln is there an online regexformat tool?  The reason why so many (including myself) get hung up on step count is because it is so quick and easy to use; plus we can link the patterns in our answers to an informative demo page that anyone can easily access.  Having your suggested tool available to the public without download would surely help to bring people out of the dark ages and reduce your time spent arguing with less informed folks.

Comment: @mickmackusa - Hello, I think RxF is a full-blown app. Actually more like a suite of apps. The benchmark is just one part of it. There is probably a reason why there is no good online regex benchmark tool considering putting a strict timing process on a website. The bench runs a separate task at higher than normal schedule. About the _steps_; a single step can be comparing a regex literal `a` as well as comparing a regex class `[...]`. Both are 1 step. A _class_ is a list of pre-compiled items that could require intensive analysis. Each is a single _state_ (or step).

Comment: @mickmackusa - _Steps (con't)_ : Good example. Given `abcddcba` two regex both report 18 steps from regex101. Benchmark is different. When you add up the timings across the entire regex, differences open up steps < - > timings. `Regex1:   [abcd]
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   8
Elapsed Time:    0.32 s,   315.51 ms,   315514 µs
Matches per sec:   1,267,772

Regex2:   [a-d]
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   8
Elapsed Time:    0.36 s,   359.98 ms,   359980 µs
Matches per sec:   1,111,172`

Comment: Thanks for exlaining, but this reality has been explain to me enough times by a sufficient number of StackOverflow regex-wizards that I don't refute it. So there is no shortcut? I need to download the suite to deepen my understanding of true pattern performance?

Comment: @mickmackusa - I guess you have to download it. It runs on windows. For you, I'll send you a key. Just email support with your full name and tell e'm sln sent you (reference this comment).

Comment: @mickmackusa - No, I'm not in charge over there. Must follow protocol.

Comment: @sln error presented blocking the install. (_Error 0x80070666: Cannot install a product when a newer version is installed._)  I don't have time to sort this out at the moment.  Thanks, I'll look into this as soon as I can.

Comment: @mickmackusa - Thanks. Microsoft retroactively introduces a bug in their setup vcredistributible installer. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/58bac38c-4c28-40d3-b840-1c71ddefe0c1/vc-2015-redist-wont-install-if-vc-2017-redist-is-installed?forum=vssetup I've informed product support.

Comment: @mickmackusa - They posted a new setup. Installs ok for me, I have vs2017 runtime installed. Try it again. It looks like they took out a 2015 prerequisite, so it won't install automatically.

Comment: Seamless install today.

Answer (score 4):

I'd try not to use a regex and instead extract it from the DOM using PHP's standard [DOMDocument XML manipulation library](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//form[contains(@class, "user_session_form")]/input[contains(@name, "authenticity_token")]';
$inputs= $xpath->query($query);
foreach($inputs as $input) {
    echo $input->getAttribute('value');
}
```

The `$query` variable is an [xpath query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php).

Comment: Looks great, and seems more ideal! Will also test out a minute.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, always best to avoid regex if the desired result is achievable another way, within reason (respect to time to create the solution).

Comment: In the case of parsing HTML/DOM documents, I'd agree. Your's I tried earlier but could not get to work (not that it doesn't work, I just have to pinpoint where It's missing the selector more I suppose.  Just right clicking it in Chrome developer tools brought back `//*[@id="main_login_form"]/div/div[3]/form/input[2]` which yours is obviously more precise and flexible to changes (but so is @sln's answer as well ;). RegEX is great if you know it, I'd say mostly for text parsing, but if you know it and can flex your way around elements like that there's a lot you can do.

Comment: Note I just tried them as is, haven't had a chance to really look into them yet. Will this weekend.

Comment: This is a clean and sensible solution. It has the added benefit of validating the xml efficiently while serialising the data. Regex is for matching strings that can vary a lot and do not necessarily confirm to a standard. Using regex to match if you're confident in the format and structure can be useful, but for validation it is not. It is bad practice. For that reason this shouldbe the selected answer. I hope you manage to get it to work.

Comment: @bbruman you might try two separate double slashes in the query expression... https://stackoverflow.com/q/36019544/2943403 (add `/` before `/input`)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to match

`<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="{$token}"/>`

Your pattern is:

`"/<input type=\"hidden\" value=(.*?)\" name=\"authenticity_token\">/i"`

Do you see it?

It should be: `"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"authenticity_token\" value=\"([^"]+)\"\/>"`

**Edit**: If being able to match without being constrained to a particular attribute order is important:

```
<input (?:(?:type=\"hidden\"|name=\"authenticity_token\"|value=\"([^"]+)\"|(?!(?:name|type|value))[^=]+=\"[^"]+\")\s*)+
```

Will consume without capturing, any attribute and its value that is not named "type," or "name," which it requires to exist as `type="hidden"` and `name="authenticity_token"`, and if the attribute "value" is encountered, its value will be captured in capture group 1.

**Edit 2**: preg_match() and preg_replace() etc. will require delimiters at the beginning and start of the pattern: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

So you would simply encapsulate the expression like so: `"/<expression>/"` or `"~<expression>~"` where `<expression>` is your regex.

Comment: Too distracted trying to understand the whole apparently I forgot to look at the small details :)  Will try it out in a minute!

Comment: Convention is actually to end a self-closing tag with a space before the close, e.g. <br /> instead of <br/>. So you might want to add a `\s*` in there, i.e. `\s*\/>` if it appears to be inconsistent in the source.

Comment: Thanks much. Yes the first one brought back an empty array and the second one brought back `Warning: preg_match(): No ending matching delimiter '&gt;'` (same as @sln, so I'm guessing it found a match, but it's late and I haven't the time to do other than try it. I'll look into it more tomorrow.

Comment: Ah, yeah, easy fix. Some regex implementations don't like pattern delimiters (e.g. Java) so it's common to give regex without them. If your implementation needs them, just add them at the beginning and end of the pattern. PHP does require them: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php
So you'd want: `"/<input (?:(?:type=\"hidden\"|name=\"authenticity_token\"|value=\"([^"]+)\"|(?!(?:name|type|value))[^=]+=\"[^"]+\")\s*)+/"`

Comment: Ha, yes. I like it.. it actually brings back in the entire hidden form in the array response https://i.imgur.com/Hu66CHF.png .. tempted to change the answer to this, as @sln pattern brings back empty array elements then the token (albeit already trimmed and in text form) before the token is captured. Either way good stuff and thank you, yours is obviously much simpler to understand and wrap ones head around :)