# Nokogiri xpath - count occurences of XML element with conditions on attributes

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have this tags in my XML :

```
<rooms>
   <room id="1" beds="1" windows="0"/>
   <room id="2" beds="2" windows="0"/>
   <room id="3" beds="2" windows="0"/>
 </rooms>
```

And I would like to count the occurences of rooms with 1 bed and no window and to count the occurences of rooms with 2 beds and no window. I use nokogiri xpath in Ruby, so I am looking for something like this :

count of this -> `xpath: "//rooms//room[@beds=1 and @windows=0]"`

count of this -> `xpath: "//rooms//room[@beds=2 and @windows=0]"`

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried with `doc.search("//rooms//room[@beds=2 and @windows=0]").count`?

Comment: `//rooms//room` should be `//rooms/room`. `//` and `/` are different. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/36019544/128421.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping the XPath expressions with `count()`. So:

```
count(//rooms//room[@beds=1 and @windows=0])
```

and

```
count(/rooms//room[@beds=2 and @windows=0])
```

should output `1` and `2`, respectively.

Comment: Can I get it in string instead of float ?

Comment: @NoémieHarvey - yes, just wrap the whole thing once again with `string()`.