# what is the difference between xpath //li[div]/descendant::a[2] and //li[div]//a[2]?

Tags: xpath

I am writing xpath code but I do not know the difference, when I use //li[div]//a[2] shows no results found. link: https://www.yelp.nl/search?find_desc=spa&find_loc=der%20N%C3%A4he%20von%20California%2C%20Louisville%2C%20KY%2C%20Vereinigte%20Staaten&start=70

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`//` is a shorter way of writing `/descendant-or-self::node()/`.

In some structures, it can return different nodes:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div><b>
      <a id="1"></a>
      <a id="2"></a>
      <p>
        <a id="3"></a>
        <a id="4"></a>
      </p>
    </b></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><b>
      <a id="5"></a>
      <a id="6"></a>
      <p>
        <a id="7"></a>
        <a id="8"></a>
      </p>
    </b></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now, only ids 2 and 6 correspond to `//li[div]/descendant::a[2]`,
but `//li[div]//a[2]` matches 2, 4, 6, and 8.

See [Abbreviated Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/#abbrev) in the XML Path Language (XPath) specification.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36020488/1405588 says `descendant-or-self::` - which is correct?

Comment: Neither, sorry. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Neither, really?  If you're saying some part of [stackoverflow.com/a/36020488/1405588](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36020488/290085)  is incorrect, please specify.

Comment: @kjhughes: It's neither `/descendant::` nor `/descendant-or-self::`, it's `/descendant-or-self::node()/`.

Comment: The linked answer (which I wrote) does say `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, so it is correct.  @o11c was also correct to point out your initial mistake, which was that you got the *axis* wrong.  @o11c provided you with the correct axis and a correct reference, not the full expansion of the `//` abbreviation.   His comment and his referenced answer were both on the mark and helpful.

Comment: Beyond the obvious expansion of `//` difference, the key difference between those two XPaths is how `[2]` is interpreted differently along those two axis.  See duplicate link for further details on this difference.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the link was helpful. The "says `descendant-or-self::`" was the part I replied to.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.  +1