# selenium XPATH match </html>

Tags: selenium, xpath

What is the XPATH of matching the `</html>` tag in Selenium ? I want to make a "Wait" object. It waits until the `</html>` is seen in the html file.

```
public class SimpleChrome {
  private ChromeDriver driver;
  private void WaitForPageLoad()
  {
      var wait = MakeDefaultWait();
      wait.Until(x => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)x).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
  }
  DefaultWait<IWebDriver> MakeDefaultWait()
  {
      DefaultWait<IWebDriver> fluentWait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
      fluentWait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
      fluentWait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
      fluentWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
      fluentWait.Message = "Element to be searched not found";
      return fluentWait;
  }
  public SimpleChrome()
  {
      ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
      opt.AddArgument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
      opt.AddExcludedArguments("enable-automation");
      opt.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
      driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
  }
  public void GoToURL()
  {
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
      WaitForPageLoad();
  }
}
```

What I try to do is I created a wrapper to do the Selenium thing It has a function called `GoToURL`. Inside the function, I go to a url and wait for it. I find that the page I load has all the information I need when I see `</html>`. As a result, I want to change the `WaitForPageLoad()` to use XPATH is detect complete loading. The XPATH need to handle detect `</html>`

Comment: `"//html"` thats all!

Comment: You probably don't want to actually do this. the get method will do some of this waiting for you. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MosheSlavin, `//` has its own meaning in xpath. It seems it searchs `html` from current node.

Comment: @Alex I know a bit about xpath... as DMart asked what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What does // mean , see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019544/if-double-slash-is-used-2-times-in-xpath-what-does-it-mean/36020053

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
/html
```

I assume to use XPath in selenium/browser the dom already must be completely loaded.