# Xpath for loop gives only first result. How do I get all of them? (Python, Scrapy)

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to get all results that have specific class name in them. Xpath for loop only gives the first result.

Heres the code:

```
for links in response.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div/div[contains(@class, 'ZINbbc xpd O9g5cc uUPGi')]"):
        link = links.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'kCrYT')]/a/@href").get()

        header = links.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'kCrYT')]/a/h3/div/text()").get()
```

I've tried adding `[position()>=3 and position(<=14]` to the first div too.

Edit: Heres the HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div>...</div>(Don't need this one)
    <styles>...</styles>
    <div>...</div>
    <div class="ZINbbc xpd O9g5cc uUPGi">
        <div class="kCrYT">
            <a href="link">
                <h3 class="zBAuLc">
                    <div class="BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd">Title</div>
                </h3>
.......
```

Comment: Pleas share the html.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed Added HTML

Comment: off-topic: class names look like changed from what was in the source code. What is more possible, is that class names **will** change in time. I suggest using a different approach in here.

Comment: @SerhiiShynkarenko Its from google search results. I don't this they have changed since I run same code for few days now. I solved issue by using css selectors. They are easier and seems to work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single slash is for the absolute path, I am pretty sure.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-xpaths

[If double slash (//) is used 2 times in XPath, what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019544/if-double-slash-is-used-2-times-in-xpath-what-does-it-mean/36020053)