# how to exclude a table inside in another table in xpath?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have the follow html file:

```
<table class="pd-table">
<caption> Tech </caption>
<tbody>
    <tr data-group="1">
        <td> Electrical </td>
        <td> Design </td>
    <tr data-group="1">
        <td> Output </td>
        <td> Function </td>
    <tr data-group="7">
        <td> EMC </td>
        <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> EN 6547 ESD </td>
                <td> EN 8901 ESD </td>
    <tr data-group="8">
        <td> Weight [8] </td>
        <td> 27.7 </td>
```

I can isolate EN 6547 ESD and EN 8901 ESD with the follow xpath:

```
//table[@class="pd-table"]//tbody//tr//td/table//tr//td/text()').getall()
```

Any other way is always welcome :)

Another data which I would like to get is to get all the rest of the data without the previous isolated.

Is there any way to do it? :)

Comment: What do you exactly mean with “ Another data which I would like to get is to get all the rest of the data without the previous isolated” ?

Comment: I would like to exclude the second table where is EN 65647 ESD and EN 8901 ESD. Getting all the remaining information from the html

Answer (score 0):

Your used Xpath uses a lot of unwanted double slash.
[See meaning of double slash in Xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36020488/3710053).
The less you use double slash, the better it will perform.
So just use single slash like this:

```
//table[@class="pd-table"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tr/td/text()
```

Another way of selecting td's that have two ancestor::table

```
//td[count(ancestor::table)=2]/text()
```

**And that leads to the answer of your second question:**

```
//td[count(ancestor::table)=1]/text()
```

An other possibility would just be:

```
//table[@class="pd-table"]/tbody/tr/td/text()
```

Or(assuming the second tabel does not have tr's with @data-group):

```
//tr[@data-group]/td/text()
```

So you see there are many Xpath's lead to Rome ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `table` tag is not closed properly in `data-group-7`...
Anyway in such cases you can stick to text content of the cell using `contains()` or `text()="some exact text"`

```
response.xpath('//td[contains(text(), "EMC")]').css('td~table tbody td::text').extract()
```