# Chain an "and" in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following valid xpath:

```xml
//products/product/territory[text()="CA"]/../sales_start_date[text()="2023-05-05"]/..
```

Against this xml:

```xml
<products>
    <product>
        <territory>CA</territory>
        <cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
        <sales_start_date>2023-05-05</sales_start_date>
        <bundle_only>false</bundle_only>
    </product>
    <product>
        <territory>US</territory>
        <cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
        <sales_start_date>2023-05-05</sales_start_date>
        <bundle_only>false</bundle_only>
    </product>
</products>
```

[image]

Is there a way to do this pattern without having to descend and then backtrack? Conceptually, something like:

```xml
//products/product[territory:text()="CA" and sales_start_date:text()="2023-05-05"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this `XPath`, no need `text()`:

```
'//products/product[territory="CA" and sales_start_date="2023-05-05"]'
```

All `XPath` versions. Compatible with `XPath 1`

Answer (score 3):

You can nest the brackets:

```xml
//products/product[territory[text()="CA"] and sales_start_date[text()="2023-05-05"]]
```

You can also omit the `text()` lookups and do:

```xml
//products/product[territory="CA" and sales_start_date="2023-05-05"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use 2 [predicates](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_predicate.htm), like this:

```
/products/product[territory/text()="CA"][sales_start_date/text()="2023-05-05"]
```

Be careful using [`//`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36020053/3710053) in XPath, at large xml-documents it could slow down your code.