# How to handle changing ids in XPath for Selenium automation testing?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, xpath, automation

When refreshing the page, the ID attribute's value `3647323225296998740` of the HTML node changes each time.

Is there a way to construct XPath expression for dynamic attribute value?

Is there a way to deal with this kind of circumstance during Selenium Automation testing and expect a proper, detailed response?

Comment: Select the element by some other attribute and don't use the `id` attribute. If you want specific help you will have to post more detail about your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try using XPath functions like :Following , Preceding siblings:

Syntax: `//tagname[@attribute=’value’]//following-sibling::tagname`

Syntax: `//tagname[@attribute=’value’]//following-sibling::tagname`

Xpath: `//span[@data-name=’your-name’]//child::input`

Comment: See this question on when to use double slashes and when not: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36019544/3710053

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).