# XSLT foreach wrong value

Tags: xslt

I am having some difficulty selecting the correct value in my loop.
my loop does not retrieve the associated values.

Resume of File.xml

```
<WKIUserSpecifiedAttributesRoot>
            <EntityRef Ref_ID="ID_17">
                <Attribute name="Difficulty" >
                    <Value>Low</Value>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute name="Title" >
                    <Value> 5 </Value>
                </Attribute>
            </EntityRef>
            <EntityRef Ref_ID="ID_19">
                <Attribute name="Difficulty" >
                    <Value>hight</Value>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute name="Title" >
                    <Value> 10 </Value>
                </Attribute>
            </EntityRef>
</WKIUserSpecifiedAttributesRoot>
```

file.xslt

```
<xsl:for-each select="$P_DataXMLRoot/WKIPreviewDataRoot/WKIUserSpecifiedAttributesRoot/EntityRef">
   <xsl:value-of select="//Attribute[@name = 'Title']" />
   <xsl:value-of select="//Attribute[@name = 'Difficulty']" />
 </xsl:for-each>
```

I recover many values ​​but not the one that corresponds to the Ref_Id, All my data are the same.
I only provide 2 Entity_Refs in the example but I have many more but only the value of the first Entity_Ref appears in all the results of the loop.

Thank you Verry Much.

Comment: change `//Attribute ` to `Attribute`
see for more info on use of `//` this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36020488/3710053

Comment: Classic "magic fairy dust" problem - using syntax without understanding it because you saw it in an example somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the posted XML, you would want something like this :

```
<xsl:for-each select="$P_DataXMLRoot/WKIUserSpecifiedAttributesRoot/EntityRef">
  <xsl:value-of select="Attribute[@name = 'Title']/Value" />
  <xsl:value-of select="Attribute[@name = 'Difficulty']/Value" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Using *//* goes back to the beginning of your document and traverses it to find all elements corresponding to your XPath.

Comment: ... and in XSLT 1.0 (which you're obviously using, although you neglected to mention this in your question), `xsl:value-of` will only output the value of the first one.