# python-docx: matching an lxml element using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, python-docx

I'm trying to access the underlying `lxml` data of a cell of a table in a docx file using [python-docx](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/) library in order to change the `val` attribute of an element.

```
from docx import Document

doc = Document("test.docx")
table = doc.tables[0]
target_cell = table.cell(0, 0)

print(target_cell._tc.xml)
```

Up to this point, everything works and I can get the `lxml` of the cell which is this:

```
<w:tc xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16cex="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml/cex" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml" xmlns:w16sdtdh="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2020/wordml/sdtdatahash" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
  <w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="1024" w:type="pct"/>
    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
  </w:tcPr>
  <w:p w14:paraId="33557991" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00B07513" w:rsidRPr="00F2422D" w:rsidRDefault="00B07513" w:rsidP="0081609A">
    <w:pPr>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:cs="B Yekan"/>
        <w:sz w:val="12"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="12"/>
      </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:cs="B Yekan"/>
        <w:noProof/>
      </w:rPr>
      <mc:AlternateContent>
        <mc:Choice Requires="wps">
          <w:drawing>
            <wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251704320" behindDoc="0" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1" wp14:anchorId="7C3C7F8B" wp14:editId="073786DF">
              <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
              <wp:positionH relativeFrom="column">
                <wp:posOffset>-1270</wp:posOffset>
              </wp:positionH>
              <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph">
                <wp:posOffset>3175</wp:posOffset>
              </wp:positionV>
              <wp:extent cx="232426" cy="88265"/>
              <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="15240" b="26035"/>
              <wp:wrapNone/>
              <wp:docPr id="271" name="Rectangle: Rounded Corners 271"/>
              <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>
              <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
                  <wps:wsp>
                    <wps:cNvSpPr/>
                    <wps:spPr>
                      <a:xfrm>
                        <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                        <a:ext cx="232426" cy="88265"/>
                      </a:xfrm>
                      <a:prstGeom prst="roundRect">
                        <a:avLst>
                          <a:gd name="adj" fmla="val 39243"/>
                        </a:avLst>
                      </a:prstGeom>
                      <a:solidFill>
                        <a:srgbClr val="FFFF00"/>
                      </a:solidFill>
                      <a:ln>
                        <a:solidFill>
                          <a:schemeClr val="bg1">
                            <a:lumMod val="95000"/>
                          </a:schemeClr>
                        </a:solidFill>
                      </a:ln>
                    </wps:spPr>
                    <wps:style>
                      <a:lnRef idx="2">
                        <a:schemeClr val="accent1">
                          <a:shade val="50000"/>
                        </a:schemeClr>
                      </a:lnRef>
                      <a:fillRef idx="1">
                        <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                      </a:fillRef>
                      <a:effectRef idx="0">
                        <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                      </a:effectRef>
                      <a:fontRef idx="minor">
                        <a:schemeClr val="lt1"/>
                      </a:fontRef>
                    </wps:style>
                    <wps:bodyPr rot="0" spcFirstLastPara="0" vertOverflow="overflow" horzOverflow="overflow" vert="horz" wrap="square" lIns="91440" tIns="45720" rIns="91440" bIns="45720" numCol="1" spcCol="0" rtlCol="0" fromWordArt="0" anchor="ctr" anchorCtr="0" forceAA="0" compatLnSpc="1">
                      <a:prstTxWarp prst="textNoShape">
                        <a:avLst/>
                      </a:prstTxWarp>
                      <a:noAutofit/>
                    </wps:bodyPr>
                  </wps:wsp>
                </a:graphicData>
              </a:graphic>
              <wp14:sizeRelH relativeFrom="margin">
                <wp14:pctWidth>0</wp14:pctWidth>
              </wp14:sizeRelH>
            </wp:anchor>
          </w:drawing>
        </mc:Choice>
        <mc:Fallback>
          <w:pict>
            <v:roundrect w14:anchorId="2887428C" id="Rectangle: Rounded Corners 271" o:spid="_x0000_s1026" style="position:absolute;margin-left:-.1pt;margin-top:.25pt;width:18.3pt;height:6.95pt;z-index:251704320;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-width-percent:0;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;mso-width-percent:0;mso-width-relative:margin;v-text-anchor:middle" arcsize="25716f" o:gfxdata="UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbJSRQU7DMBBF&#10;90jcwfIWJU67QAgl6YK0S0CoHGBkTxKLZGx5TGhvj5O2G0SRWNoz/78nu9wcxkFMGNg6quQqL6RA&#10;0s5Y6ir5vt9lD1JwBDIwOMJKHpHlpr69KfdHjyxSmriSfYz+USnWPY7AufNIadK6MEJMx9ApD/oD&#10;OlTrorhX2lFEilmcO2RdNtjC5xDF9pCuTyYBB5bi6bQ4syoJ3g9WQ0ymaiLzg5KdCXlKLjvcW893&#10;SUOqXwnz5DrgnHtJTxOsQfEKIT7DmDSUCaxw7Rqn8787ZsmRM9e2VmPeBN4uqYvTtW7jvijg9N/y&#10;JsXecLq0q+WD6m8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#10;bHOkkMFqwzAMhu+DvYPRfXGawxijTi+j0GvpHsDYimMaW0Yy2fr2M4PBMnrbUb/Q94l/f/hMi1qR&#10;JVI2sOt6UJgd+ZiDgffL8ekFlFSbvV0oo4EbChzGx4f9GRdb25HMsYhqlCwG5lrLq9biZkxWOiqY&#10;22YiTra2kYMu1l1tQD30/bPm3wwYN0x18gb45AdQl1tp5j/sFB2T0FQ7R0nTNEV3j6o9feQzro1i&#10;OWA14Fm+Q8a1a8+Bvu/d/dMb2JY5uiPbhG/ktn4cqGU/er3pcvwCAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAA&#10;IQA4fUuVzAIAABUGAAAOAAAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWysVEtv2zAMvg/YfxB0X+24adcGdYogRYYB&#10;XVu0HXpWZCn2IImapLz260fJj6RrscOwHBTRJD+Sn0heXe+0IhvhfAOmpKOTnBJhOFSNWZX0+/Pi&#10;0wUlPjBTMQVGlHQvPL2efvxwtbUTUUANqhKOIIjxk60taR2CnWSZ57XQzJ+AFQaVEpxmAUW3yirH&#10;toiuVVbk+Xm2BVdZB1x4j19vWiWdJnwpBQ/3UnoRiCop5hbS6dK5jGc2vWKTlWO2bniXBvuHLDRr&#10;DAYdoG5YYGTtmjdQuuEOPMhwwkFnIGXDRaoBqxnlf1TzVDMrUi1IjrcDTf7/wfK7zYMjTVXS4vOI&#10;EsM0PtIj0sbMSokJeYS1qURF5uAMvjKJVsjZ1voJuj7ZB9dJHq+RgJ10Ov5jaWSXeN4PPItdIBw/&#10;FqfFuDinhKPq4qI4P4uQ2cHXOh++CNAkXkrqYg4xp8Qw29z6kKiuunRZ9YMSqRU+3IYpcnpZjE87&#10;xM4YsXvM6OlBNdWiUSoJbrWcK0fQtaQL/OWpK9DllZkybz1jk4rBd7kapQTVWn+DqsW7PMsPcL15&#10;qvUIHENF9CyS2tKYbmGvRIypzKOQ+ESRuBQgDcchLuNcmNDG9jWrRBs6Rh4qeRU6AUZkiRQM2B1A&#10;b9mC9Njt+3T20VWk2Rqc878l1joPHikymDA468aAew9AYVVd5Na+J6mlJrK0hGqPDeygnWxv+aLB&#10;prllPjwwhx2BQ4/rKdzjIRVsSwrdjZIa3K/3vkd7nDDUUrLF1VBS/3PNnKBEfTU4e5ej8TjukiSM&#10;zz4XKLhjzfJYY9Z6DthaOF2YXbpG+6D6q3SgX3CLzWJUVDHDMXZJeXC9MA/tysI9yMVslsxwf1gW&#10;bs2T5RE8shp7/Hn3wpztJifgxN1Bv0bYJI1Dy+jBNnoamK0DyCZE5YHXTsDdg7dXy+1YTlaHbT79&#10;DQAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAxK9X+9kAAAAEAQAADwAAAGRycy9kb3ducmV2LnhtbEyOQU+D&#10;QBBG7yb+h82YeGuXVmgMsjTGxoMHE1uNXgd2BCI7i+zS4r93PNnj5Ht584rt7Hp1pDF0ng2slgko&#10;4trbjhsDb6+Pi1tQISJb7D2TgR8KsC0vLwrMrT/xno6H2CiRcMjRQBvjkGsd6pYchqUfiGX79KPD&#10;KOfYaDviSeSu1+sk2WiHHcuHFgd6aKn+OkxOLO/fqw+7n/jJheeueamGXbbLjLm+mu/vQEWa4z8M&#10;f/mSDqU0VX5iG1RvYLEW0EAGSsabTQqqEihNQZeFPo8vfwEAAP//AwBQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEA&#10;toM4kv4AAADhAQAAEwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbFBLAQItABQA&#10;BgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC8BAABfcmVscy8ucmVsc1BLAQItABQA&#10;BgAIAAAAIQA4fUuVzAIAABUGAAAOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC4CAABkcnMvZTJvRG9jLnhtbFBLAQIt&#10;ABQABgAIAAAAIQDEr1f72QAAAAQBAAAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACYFAABkcnMvZG93bnJldi54bWxQ&#10;SwUGAAAAAAQABADzAAAALAYAAAAA&#10;" fillcolor="yellow" strokecolor="#f2f2f2 [3052]" strokeweight="1pt">
              <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
            </v:roundrect>
          </w:pict>
        </mc:Fallback>
      </mc:AlternateContent>
    </w:r>
  </w:p>
</w:tc>
```

I'm looking for `a:solidFill` element which as it's obvious from the above output, there's only two of them but when I'm trying to get that element using `xpath`, I'm getting back many more matches.

```
solidFills = target_cell._tc.xpath('//a:solidFill')
print(len(solidFills)) #86
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Starting a XPath with `//` will find everything somewhere in the xml. You need to start it with a `.` telling the engine to use the current context

Comment: See this answer for a good understanding https://stackoverflow.com/a/36020488/3710053

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed thanks for the link. I didn't know that `//` matches against all of the context node